# Java How shift byte is working in data sending to websockets

Tags: java, websocket, bit-manipulation

```
    op.write((byte)((len >> 56) & (byte)255));
    op.write((byte)((len >> 48) & (byte)255));
    op.write((byte)((len >> 40) & (byte)255));
    op.write((byte)((len >> 32) & (byte)255));
    op.write((byte)((len >> 24) & (byte)255));
    op.write((byte)((len >> 16) & (byte)255));
    op.write((byte)((len >> 8) & (byte)255));
    op.write((byte)(len & 255));
```

I'am trying to understand what means this shiftings in the examples of sending data to websockets when the payload exceeds 65536 bytes, why the shifting begins from 56 to 8 bytes? what is the purpose of this?

I get this results when printing out in this order:

```
0
1
12
175
0
1
12
175
```

how can I understand if this is the right values? cause I can't find detailed explanation of this in the RFC or documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shifting operates on bits, not bytes. Shifting more than 32 bits at a time only makes sense if `len` is more than 32 bits in size.  This code is sending an **8-byte** integer value to the peer, so `len` must be a 64bit `long`.

The numeric values `0 1 12 175 0 1 12 175` is the byte sequence (in hex) `00 01 0C AF 00 01 0C AF`.  If you reverse the shifts and concat them together:

```
long len = (((long)0) << 56) |
           (((long)1) << 48) |
           (((long)12) << 40)|
           (((long)175) << 32)|
           (((long)0) << 24) |
           (((long)1) << 16) |
           (((long)12) << 8) |
             (long)175;
```

You end up with 295420735589551. Is that your original `len` value?  If not, then your source `len` value was not correct to begin with.

Comment: the len is a textBytes.length; it is an integer value, should I convert it to long?, please a little example...

Comment: An `int` is a 32bit data type, you can't shift it more than 32 bits. If the peer is expecting a 64-bit value, then you have to cast the `int` to `long` first, then shift it as needed. But the higher 4 bytes will always be zeroes in that case.

Comment: yes, thank you very much I've changed the int type to long and it worked, thats was my problem!